# Using DateDiff() to find the difference between getDate() and a concatonated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, datediff, date-conversion

I am trying to find the difference between today's date and a value that is a concatenation of mulitple values but begins with an 8 digit date without any dashes or forward slashes.  There's something wrong with my syntax I believe, but I'm not yet skilled enough to see what I'm doing incorrectly.  Here is what I have so far:

```
select DateDiff(dd, (select MIN(CAST(Left(batchid, 8) as Date)) from
[Table]), getdate()) from [Table]
```

This is returning the following error:  "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: What is the error your get? Also what do the 8 digit dates look like in your table? Are they yyyymmdd, mmddyyyy, etc...

Comment: JChao.  The date is YYYYMMDD, and the error I'm getting has been added to the post.

Comment: Well obviously there is at least one row where `batchid` doesn't start with a valid date. This is just one of many reasons we store dates as dates, not as part of some string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your have data where the left 8 is not a valid date in yyyymmdd format. Your can run the following query to find them

```
select batchid, isdate(Left(batchid, 8))
from [Table]
where isdate(Left(date, 8)) = 0
```

This is the correct syntax to your query. Your original example had an extra parenthesis which I assume was a typo since your error appears to be data related.

```
select 
    datediff(dd, (select min(cast(left(batchid, 8) as date)) 
                  from [Table]), getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks, @JChao.  This actually does work with the other table I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some more details.
Namely, what does batchid look like in 8 digit form? is it YYYYMMDD or DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY?

Also could you show us the result of the following?

```
select MIN(CAST(Left(batchid, 8) as Date))) 
from [Table])
```

Sry for using an answer, i don't have the rep to add a comment directly below.

Comment: MADnoobie.  The date is YYYYMMDD, and when using the query you gave me, it returns "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 0):

This was may error.  I was working with another table and forgot batchID was not the same for both.  The concatenated batchID in the table I posted a question about can't be converted to a date.